# How to fix pyinstaller build issue?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, dylib, pyside6

I build a mac app with pyinstaller with pyside6==6.5.1.1 coding, but when open app, it shows error, I don't konw how to fix this:
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/v7/86wq9s_x2wgdhtbk6d5msjh00000gn/T/_MEInhbCGW/PySide6/QtGui.abi3.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtDBus
Referenced from: /private/var/folders/v7/86wq9s_x2wgdhtbk6d5msjh00000gn/T/_MEInhbCGW/QtGui
Reason: Incompatible library version: QtGui requires version 6.0.0 or later, but QtDBus provides version 5.15.0

fix app open error issue, can normally open app

Comment: Can you run your app without bundling it with `pyinstaller`? In other worse, verify whether or not the correct version of the QtGui library is installed.

Comment: I can normally run my project in pycharm, and my python3.10 env installed in anaconda, and it still shown same error after i reinstalled pyside6.

Comment: This issue waste three days to debug, still had no solution. It worked when i modify my codes from pyside6 to pyqt5

Comment: I realize English is not your native language but we cannot make any sense out of what you are saying. And whining that is "waste three days to debug" is not going to improve the odds of getting an answer. What do you mean "I can normally run..."? I asked a very specific question. Can you run, using `python` from the command line, the program you are trying to bundle with pyinstaller? I understand you are frustrated but you seem to be flailing around with no idea what you are doing or how to debug a problem.

Comment: I'll also point out that it looks like your program has an indirect dependency on a shared library that is not bundled into the image created by pyinstaller. And when you execute that bundle it cannot find that library. Which suggests you are running `pyinstaller` on a different system than you are executing the resulting bundled Python program.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I meant that I can run my code with command line 'python ***.py', and in `pycharm` the  codes runs successfully. The error shown `QtGui requires version 6.0.0 or later, but QtDBus provides version 5.15.0` after i built a bundle with pyinstaller, but QtGui is in my latest pyside6 library, it's the latest version 6.5.1.1.  The main problem is that I do not know how to check the QtGui version or upgrade this QtGui version and related frameworks. So I reinstalled pyside6 and it still not work. So I change related UI functions to `pyqt5`, it worked after rebuilt the bundle